# Unable to Export the Dynamically added row to Gridview to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have tried Exporting GridView to Excel but observed that 
the Dynamically added last Row to Gridview  is not exported to excel.

I have two datasets first one binds the data directly to Gridview.

After Which I add the last row from another DataSet.

In the page I'm able to see the result as Expected but when exported excel I'm not.
Below is my code:

```
DataSet dsgrid = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(DBConnectionString.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_Training_GetCirclescoreCardReport  ", sqlparam);

    if (TrainingUtil.isDataSetValid(dsgrid))
    {

        RSGScoreCard_Grid.DataSource = dsgrid;
        RSGScoreCard_Grid.DataBind();
        AddOverallRow(dsgrid);
    }
    else RSGScoreCard_Grid.DataBind();
```

Adding Overall row at bottom:

```
 #region Add OverallRow
private void AddOverallRow(DataSet dsgrid)
{
    using (GridViewRow gr = new GridViewRow(RSGScoreCard_Grid.Rows.Count + 1, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)//6 is the column count for overall row
        {
            using (TableCell tc = new TableCell())
            {
                gr.Cells.Add(tc);
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    gr.Cells[i].ColumnSpan = 4;
                    gr.Cells[i].Text = "Overall";
                    gr.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("class", "fcol");
                    gr.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold;padding-left:20%");
                }
                else gr.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold");

            }
        }


        if (dsgrid.Tables[1] != null)//creating a dynamic row to gridview
            if (dsgrid.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gr.Cells[1].Text = dsgrid.Tables[1].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                gr.Cells[1].Width = Unit.Percentage(8);
                gr.Cells[2].Text = dsgrid.Tables[1].Rows[0][6].ToString();
                gr.Cells[2].Width = Unit.Percentage(8);
                gr.Cells[3].Text = dsgrid.Tables[1].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                gr.Cells[3].Width = Unit.Percentage(8);
                gr.Cells[4].Text = dsgrid.Tables[1].Rows[0][8].ToString();
                gr.Cells[4].Width = Unit.Percentage(8);
                gr.Cells[5].Text = dsgrid.Tables[1].Rows[0][9].ToString();
                gr.Cells[5].Width = Unit.Percentage(8);
            }
        gr.Attributes.Add("class", "row2");

        RSGScoreCard_Grid.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(RSGScoreCard_Grid.Rows.Count + 1, gr);


    }
}
#endregion
```

and Last my code to Export the GrieView:

```
 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TrainingUtil.Export(ddlOptions.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty) + "_" + ddlVerticals.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty) + "_" + ddlLernerGroups.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty), RSGScoreCard_Grid, "For the Month/Year: " + ddlFromMonths.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()+"/"+ddlYears.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(), RSGScoreCard_Grid.HeaderRow.Cells.Count);
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}
```

the Export Method in TrainingUtil class

```
  #region Export

public static void Export(string filename, GridView grid, string Heading, int ColumnsCount)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename + ".xls"));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            grid.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
            //Cells color settings
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = String.Format("{0}", Heading);
            cell.ColumnSpan = ColumnsCount;
            cell.Attributes.Add("align", "center");
            cell.Attributes.Add("class", "yellow");
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            grid.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, row);
            foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grid.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell tcGridCells in gridRow.Cells)
                {
                    tcGridCells.Attributes.Add("class", "sborder");
                }
            }

            grid.RenderControl(htw);
            //Add the style sheet class here
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<style> .sborder { color : Black;border : 1px Solid Black; } .yellow {background-color:yellow;color:black;} </style> ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }

}
#endregion
```

Can any help me out.Why I'm not able to export the last row.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in every post back your not binding the dynamically added rows.
 Try to find the control which cause the postback and bind the data once again.

**Code to find the postback control ex:-**

```
 public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
    Control control = null;

    string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
    {
        control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return control;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ganesha after thinking about Postback process I have written the code directly in the button click event instead of finding the control and calling the function.